# which is the best method to populate Crystal Report?

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

Hello i am developing a Database web application and i am having many reports to populate. I just want to know which one is the Best method among the following which will give me fast and accurate result as the data is going to be in 1000's.

1. Through populating Dataset?
2. Through DataReader ?
3. Through Array List ?

I am using 3 tier architecture. so what if i am writing a function which would be the most appropriate return type of the function in DATA Access Layer ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use "push" method to set the data with a DataSet - this will give you the advantage to set the datasource for the main report and all subreports in one call to the database. However there are some limitations, for example you will be not able to use subreports in the details section.
I am not sure you can use datareader and array list as datasources. Even if you can I cannot see any advantages. Using datareader means that you will keep your connection to the database open while report is rendered ( the first pass). This may take some time and is not necessary. Array list ( if can be used) will allow you to set the data for one table - it is a flat structure - no relations. In most of the cases you probably will load the array-list from the database anyway so it will not make sense to get the data load it in an array and use the array to set one table if you can use a dataset.

Why you are ignoring the regular "pull" method ? It will be simpler.